# Django React: API HTML Response not rendering no the browser

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

As an exercise, I was trying to render and HTML Response trying to use Django Rest Framework Renderers. 
I have a React frontend that sends a post request to the API

request in a react component

```
axios.get('/api/upload_photo', config).then(res => res.render())
```

router

```
router.register("api/upload_photo", UploadPhotoViewSet, "upload_photo")
```

API

```
class UploadPhotoViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    parser_class = (FileUploadParser,)
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]

    def list(self, request, format=None):

        return Response({}, template_name='api/test.html')
```

template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HEEEEEY it worked</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is I get the response with the Html page but it's just as response and the Html doesn't render on the browser

Comment: what you want as a response and what you are trying to send in post request?? can you explain the requirement and what you are getting? @patrik

Comment: for now, I was trying to send as response just the template (test.html) with an empty dictionary. As for the post request, sorry it's a mistake, it's a get request.
In my project I have a post request that sends a photo and I was getting serailised data as response, I wanted to render them in a template. But for the sake of the question I would be happy to just render the plain html template doesn't matter if it's a get or a post to me for now @abhikumar22.

Comment: For what I'm currently getting, I get the template in the response when I check the dev tools but what I want is to render on the browser what I'm getting as response. To be more specific:
-I click on the button to send the api request,
- the api replies by sending the html page in the response, 
- the page doesn't change, the html is just written in the content of the response
Hope it's clear, pleas let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: please share the desired request and response in detail